# Elasticsearch: After update index analyzer, index need a reindex?

Tags: elasticsearch

If i update index analyzer like synonyms or keywords, i need to reindex the documents?

I notice some strange search result after analyzer update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. You need all your data to be indexed in the same way. This could be the reason for getting "strange" results. The data that was already indexed was indexed according to the rules of the previously defined analyzers. Any data you index after changing the analyzers is indexed by the new rules.

And since your query also now gets analyzed by the new rules, it might not produce results from the old indexed data set.
You can easily reindex data now through the elastic reindex api. Read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html
If you are concerned about Down-time, then you can read: https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

You can create a new index (index_name_v1) with the desired settings that you want. Next you can use the reindex API:

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_name_v1"
  }
}
```

Comment: but this changes the index name? if i want preserve original name?

Comment: you can first create an alias on your old index. and use that alias name in your code. 
after you have reindexed the data into a new index, then you can remove the alias from the old index and add it to the new one in one atomic operation.


POST /_aliases -d 
{
    "actions": [
        { "remove": {
            "alias": "my_index",
            "index": "my_index_v1"
        }},
        { "add": {
            "alias": "my_index",
            "index": "my_index_v1"
        }}
    ]
}


Read https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime for more details.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.  Previously indexed data will not reflect the changes as per paragraph 1 [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html).